# rm doesn't Work in script bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a sh file with 1.000.000 of instructions "rm -f", but is not working. This runs on a ubuntu server 16.04

I tried this.

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150806/5939757.tif
/bin/rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150806/5939758.tif
/bin/rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150805/5939759.tif
```

And this

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150806/5939757.tif
rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150806/5939758.tif
rm -f /media/pictures2015/pictures/FTP/20150805/5939759.tif
```

The sh file has all the permissions, but don't wokr. With the "split" command change the sh file of 1.000.000 lines to two sh files of 500.000 lines.

The output dont show any error !!!

Thank You

Comment: Do you receive any error messages? Have you verified that the files exist in their respective location(s)?

Comment: The option `-f` won't show you the errors. I am not going to advise you to remove the `-f` option, but I think you should try to `ls` the first to see if they are actually there.

Comment: There is no way you can use wildcards and/or a find to remove these?  A million lines of `rm ` in a script can't be the best solution...  Right?  Do what @Abdou, troubleshoot with 1 file.  What permissions do the `tif` files have?  What user/group does the script and the files have?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional diagnostics. How do you conclude that the command is not working? What are the permissions and ownership of the files which aren't removed?

Comment: Add the ``-v`` (verbose) option to see what happens during execution. Test it with some files from your script first.

Answer (score 0):

the error was caused because the list of the images exported from phpmyadmin and at the end of the line I am with the "CR-LF" format, so investigate how to remove it and find the dos2unix program, install it in ubuntu, run and it worked.

The final solution I found on this link [cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/)

Thanks !!!!